# Django: name of many to many items in the admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, m2m

I have a many to many field, which I'm displaying in the django admin panel.  When I add multiple items, they all come up as "ASGGroup object" in the display selector. Instead, I want them to come up as whatever the **ASGGroup.name** field is set to.  How do I do this?

My models looks like:

```
class Thing(Model):
    read_groups = ManyToManyField('ASGGroup', related_name="thing_read", blank=True)

class ASGGroup(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=63, null=True)
```

But what I'm seeing the m2m widget display is:

[image: m2m display]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `__unicode__` (or `__str__` if you are using Python 3) method on your models, so:

```
class ASGGroup(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=63, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now when your model is parsed as a string, it will return the model's `name` field, rather than the class name.